# How to prove $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (1-\cos(1/n))$ is absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus

How to prove $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (1-\cos(1/n))$ is absolutely convergent?

I can only prove it is conditionally convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$1-\cos(1/n)=2\sin^2(1/2n)\le \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

Comment: I think there's a typo in your answer: $2\sin^2(1/n)$ should be $2\sin^2(1/2n)$. This is another inequality that I'm unfamiliar with, albeit not difficult to prove.

Comment: @hank Yes, that was a typo.  This identity is effectively the double angle formula for the cosine.  Note $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$.  Now let $x=1/2n$ and solve for $\sin^2(1/2n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the inequality
$$ 1-\cos x\leq \frac{x^2}{2} $$
(which is true for all real numbers $x$), it follows that
$$ \Big|(-1)^n\Big[1-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big]\Big|=1-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\leq \frac{1}{2n^2} $$
and since $\sum\frac{1}{2n^2}$ converges, your series converges absolutely by the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Use the Cauchy condensation test, then use the ratio test